# Python visual profiler `vprof` on Windows

Tags: python, windows, pip, profiling, profiler

I would like to use the [Python visual profiler (`vprof`)](https://github.com/nvdv/vprof) on Windows.

I did `pip3 install vprof`. But that didn't create any `vprof.bat` nor `vprof.exe` anywhere. So when I try something like `vprof -c <config> <src>` in the command line (as [suggested by the readme](https://github.com/nvdv/vprof#usage)), I get "'vprof' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Should I add something specific to my environment variables?

What is `pip3 install vprof` supposed to do such that `vprof -c <config> <src>` can be called?

Comment: You probably want `python -m vprof -c ...` where `python` is the same interpreter as the one managing `pip3`

Comment: I'm guessing that wherever `pip3` is installing packages is not on your `PATH`. Can you show the output of `echo %PATH%` and `pip3 -V` to compare? It probably got put in a `Scripts` path shared with wherever that `pip3` python interpreter is

Comment: @C.Nivs `pip3 -V` says `pip 21.1.1 from c:\python39\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.9)`. `%PATH%` is `C:\Python39\;C:\Python39\Scripts\;C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts;D:\Perl\site\bin;D:\Perl\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Users\root\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\root\AppData\Roaming\npm` and so on (too long for the comment). Some directories appear multiple times in `%PATH%`. Thoughts? (I often struggle with %PATH%.) Please post your 1st comment as an answer, so I can accept it, thx!

Comment: Are you able to see anything in `C:\Python39\Scripts`? If `vprof.exe` isn't in there, you might need to just re-install it

Comment: @C.Nivs `C:\Python39\Scripts` contains only `pip.exe`, `pip3.exe`, `pip3.9.exe`. `vprof.exe` doesn't exist anywhere. Also after running `pip3 install vprof` again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want `python -m vprof -c` where `python` is the same interpreter as the one managing `pip3`

Comment: Thanks! In my case, that's `py -m vprof -c ...`.